# Can I use @ServerEndpoint as @ManagedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, websocket, managed-bean, session-scope

My ServerEndpoint  have some functions and values which I need use in webpage, can I use @ServerEndpoint as SessionScoped ManagedBean? I want use in 1 class @ServerEndpoint, @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped

Comment: Try it. Come back when you have a specific question, not a *did you try this before me* question.

Comment: No, I didn't, because I don't know which problems should be in future.. Maybe it worked, but some time later problems occured..

Comment: Again: **try it**. You have to test it first and check if you have any problem. When you have such problems, come here and ask the proper questions. We don't tend to answer *what will happen if I foo the bar*.

Comment: Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The connection has been closed.

Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started